# Как сделать автодополнение в cmd для git

Tags: windows, git

Такая проблема, когда работаю на Windows 10 с `git` то все команды приходится набирать полностью так как автодополнение в помощью `Tab`, не работает...

Нашел несколько статеек как это сделать, но ни одна не помогла...

Может кто то не давно ставил себе такое на `Windows10`?

Я помню ставил себе на Mac и все было достаточно просто, но тут прям испытание какое то...

Comment: а в **git bash** не работает автодополнение? Зачем вам cmd?

Comment: @NickVolynkin О точно, спасибо!

Comment: оформил как ответ, чуток дополнил. Раз у вас десятка, попробуйте линуксовую консоль. Может и совсем на линукс перейдёте так. )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да спасибо! У меня был Ubuntu , настолько понравилось , что купил себе мак, но на работе выдали десятку))

Comment: ну вот на свой мак поставите zsh и oh-my-zsh. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне кажется, что я уже это делал так как в терминале автодополнение работает и я помню, что что-то ставил, чтоб оно работало, так как сначала не дополняло

Comment: Автодополнение есть и в обычном баше, но чтобы с блекджеком и встроенной справкой - только в вышеупомянутой связке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автодополнение есть в git bash:

1. Откройте папку с проектом.
2. Кликните правой кнопкой мышки, нажмите <kbd>Git Bash here</kbd>
3. Используйте <kbd>Tab</kbd> для автодополнения.

Если у вас Windows 10, то рекомендую поставить Ubuntu subsystem, на неё zsh и oh-my-zsh. У вас появится автоподстановка, удобный поиск по истории и встроенная справка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть отличная роль ansible, чтобы устанавливать и настраивать вышеупомянутые инструменты like a boss:

- [Репозиторий на GitHub](https://github.com/viasite-ansible/ansible-role-zsh)
- [Статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/323496/)

Comment: В целом git bash полностью устраивает